# SQLITE error when running firebase cloud functions emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

So I'm getting this very weird error when trying to run the cloud functions emulator on my machine (it works fine in other people's machine so I'm not sure what the issue might be). It was working fine until I pulled some changes and then I started having the error. We don't even use SQLITE in our Cloud Functions so I'm totally clueless as to what might be causing this. Has anyone ever had this issue before?

[image: Error message]

Comment: It would be great if you post or share whether you have installed the Sqlite package or not in your project, in `package.json`, and check if there's any usage of sqlite in any function. Thanks

Comment: As per @Ashish , please include `package.json` in your question.